# Java optimisation corrupts my code because of generics

Tags: java, generics

The my java code example.

```
    public <T> T decode(String toDecode, Class<T> clazz) {
        return getObject(Base64.getDecoder().decode(toDecode), clazz);
    }

    private <T> T getObject(byte[] toObject, Class<T> clazz) {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(toObject);
             ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
            return (T) in.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ObjectEncoderException(e);
        }
    }
```

One works correctly for the most cases. But sometimes, when there `clazz` is incorrect type it throws `java.lang.ClassCastException` if original object persistent to decoded string is different to parametrised class type. The issue is that `ClassCastException` thrown not in the row:

```
            return (T) in.readObject();
```

It's thrown in this row:

```
        return getObject(Base64.getDecoder().decode(toDecode), clazz);
```

As result my custom exception `ObjectEncoderException` is never used.
Sure I can move my exception `catch \ throw` to different block, but let me know what I did incorrectly in this part, why it works in different way. Currently I sure this is a java issue, but possible it'd mine.

### P.S.

I've used java 17 for my experiments.

Comment: Generic types don't exist at runtime, they are erased. There is no actual cast at that point in `getObject`. If you want that, you should use `clazz.cast(in.readObject())` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, sure. this is mine issue. i missed this case, concentrating my attention on different moments. Please add this comment to answers.

Comment: Instead I closed to a duplicate that addresses this issue as well.